# Touch event going through the target element to the element in the back in cordova IOS app

Tags: cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap, cordova-ios

I have created a cordova app and I have a bootstrap(angular-ui-bootstrap) modal where i show all the input fields, I have one custom select box which opens an absolute div in front of the form's textarea and inputs, if a user taps on any of the options in that abolute positioned div then it goes through that item to the text field somehow (which is in the back form) and the virtual keyboard pops out. it is happening only on cordova ios app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've seen some similiarly weird behavior with my Cordova iOS app as well. Running the same HTML directly in iOS Safari does not produce the issue.